# how to load user-defined class in yii without ‘new’ operator？

Tags: php, yii

I am already study the Yii framework now.
With follow the manual,I put my own class 'Util' under the 'protected/componets' folder.
And I must use 'new Util()' in my model file to get the object,
Is there another way to do the same thing?
like some method writen as "getComponent()" so that I don't have to new it everytime.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If your project needs exactly one instance of the `Util` class to be available at any time, you're describing a good use case for the [Singleton programming pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html). For your use in PHP, you'd do something like:

```
<?php
class Util {
  private var $instance = false;
  private function __construct() {
    echo "No one can call 'new' but me!";
  }

  static function getInstance() {
    if ($this->instance == false) {
      // Create the first and only instance of this class
      $this->instance = new Util();
    }
    return $this->instance;
  }

  public function foo($bar) {
    echo "Hello $bar!";
  }
}
?>
```

That's the class definition. To use, simply use `$util = Util::getInstance();` to grab the one instance of the Util class. Then something like `$util->foo('World');` works just fine.